# How to use wcf service in windows phone7 application?

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7, wcf-binding, wcf-security

I have used this code in server side,

```
[OperationContract]        
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/UploadData?Name={Name}&Email={Email}&ContactNumber={ContactNumber}&DeviceModel={DeviceModel}&Problem={Problem}&Besttimetocontact={Besttimetocontact}",        
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
        NewClsMessage UploadData(string Name, string Email, string ContactNumber, string DeviceModel, string Problem, string Besttimetocontact);

 public NewClsMessage UploadData(string Name, string Email, string ContactNumber, string DeviceModel, string Problem, string Besttimetocontact)
{
            NewClsMessage ObjNewClsMessage = new NewClsMessage();
            try
            {
  str_value = "insert into Estimate(Name,Email,ContactNumber,DeviceModel,Problem,Besttimetocontact) values('" + Name + "','" + Email + "','" + ContactNumber + "','" + DeviceModel + "','" + Problem + "', '" + Besttimetocontact + "')";                 

                OpenConnection();
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                sqlCmd.CommandText = str_value;
                value = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (value > 0)
                {
                    ObjNewClsMessage = new NewClsMessage();
                    ObjNewClsMessage.Result = "1";
                    ObjNewClsMessage.Message = "send Successfully";
                }
                else
                {
                    ObjNewClsMessage = new NewClsMessage();
                    ObjNewClsMessage.Result = "0";
                    ObjNewClsMessage.Message = "Free Estimate not send Successfully";
                }
}

 catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            return ObjNewClsMessage;
```

The client side code is,

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/xml";
            //  var uri = new Uri("localhost:55666/WcfPostMethod/Service.svc/UploadXml");
            var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:50546/Service1.svc/UploadData");
            StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
            postData.AppendFormat("?{0}={1}", "Name", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("hi"));
            postData.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", "Email", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("hi@gmail.com"));
            postData.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", "ContactNumber", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("56898"));
            postData.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", "DeviceModel", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("E4376"));
            postData.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", "Problem", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Repair"));
            postData.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", "Besttimetocontact", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("9am"));            
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength] = postData.Length.ToString();
            webClient.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_UploadStringCompleted);
            webClient.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", postData.ToString());
```

Here, I am getting the error in server side..while posting the data in client app mean,in server side that data getting empty(null) values.How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us if your wcf service works without your client?

Here is a nice tool (Storm or WCF Storm)

[Storm](http://storm.codeplex.com/)

You can even find a sample:

[Consume WCF service with Windows Phone 7 Application](http://beyondrelational.com/modules/12/tutorials/382/tutorials/7684/getting-started-with-windows-phone-7-part-6-consume-wcf-service-with-windows-phone-7-application.aspx)